# How to determine virtual keyboard height?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want a button to always be exactly above the virtual keyboard. For that, I need to know the height of the keyboard. How can I do that in XF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize` in main activity and using this code worked :)

```
public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var al = new AbsoluteLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };

        var button = new BoxView {Color = Color.Red, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand};

        var entry = new Entry {HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill};

        al.Children.Add(button, new Rectangle(0, App.Dimensions.Height - 120, App.Dimensions.Width, 120));

        al.Children.Add(entry, new Rectangle(10, 50, 200, 60));

        Content = al;

        Content.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            button.Layout(new Rectangle(0, Content.Height - 120, App.Dimensions.Width, 120));
        };

    }
```

`App.Dimensions` are evaluated in MainActivity like this:

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        App.Dimensions.Height = displayMetrics.HeightPixels / displayMetrics.Density;
        App.Dimensions.Width = displayMetrics.WidthPixels / displayMetrics.Density;
```